# how do I check for only running apps using tasklist command in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, tasklist

I'm trying to print a list of running applications into a batch file, but I don't want to include the background processes on my computer. I've been experimenting with the tasklist command but can't seem to find a way to get this result.

I've already tried sorting by memory usage but this doesn't seem reliable. Any ideas?

Comment: closest would be `tasklist /apps`

Answer (score 0):

The closest i could find is as follows

```
TASKLIST /APPS /FI "STATUS eq RUNNING"
```